# UMP of a Beta($\theta,1$) distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, beta-distribution

I need to find the UMP of a random sample of a BETA$(\theta,1)$ distribution. I know that the pdf of this problem is
$$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}=\theta e^{(\theta-1)\log{x}}$$
After some calculations i get to the point that i know this family contains a MLR for $\sum_{i=1}^n\log{x_i}$. This is were i get stuck. How do i have to proceed to find the UMP? Extra information: it's the UMP, size $\alpha$, test for $H_0:\theta_0\leq1$ versus $H_a:\theta>1$.

Thanks for any help

Comment: How did you actually find this pdf?

Comment: Start by deriving the likelihood ratio statistic, determine if it's monotone, show that it's equivalent to a simple hypothesis, and use neyman Pearson.

Comment: @AdamO How can you show a likelihood ratio test statistic is equivalent to a simple hypothesis? Is it by a theorem?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick solution:

We know that $T = - \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)$ is sufficient for  $\theta$. Since $-\log(X_i) \sim $ Exp$(\frac{1}{\theta})$, $T \sim $ Gamma$(n, \frac{1}{\theta})$. Using this it's easy to show that $T$ has an MLR.

The UMP level $\alpha$ test rejects $H_0$ if $T < k$, where $k$ is chosen to satisfy $P(T < k | \theta = 1) = \alpha$. However, if $H_0: \theta = 1$ is true, then $T \sim $ Gamma$(n, 1)$ which is difficult to work with. So use the fact that $2T \sim $ Gamma$(n, 2) \stackrel{d}{=} \chi^2_{2n}$ to find $k$.